# jqueryui form submit button and using the dialog buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I've been so frustrated by this I'm going crazy!
I have a form that works if you use the submit button on the form.

I'm trying to drop it into a modal jqueryui dialog

so if you remove the input submit button in the html, the jqueryui button starts working, but breaks my action page.

normally the action page sends an email with the contents, then redirects to a thank you page

which is what it does with the html submit button, but using the jqueryui button it prints this:

```
 Â
```

and doesn't continue

This is the section where the button is initialized

```
 $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  height: 400,
  width: 350,
  modal: true,
  buttons: {
    "Submit Request": function() {

   $("form[name='send']").submit()
   $('#send').submit();
      $(this).submit();
    $('#dialog-form').submit();
```

and this is the form

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Request a Quote">
<p class="validateTips">You are also welcome to call us at </p>

<form id="send" name="send" action="process.php" method="POST">
<label for="name">Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
<label for="email">Email</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
<label for="number">Phone Number</label>
<input type="name" name="contact" id="number" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
<label for="message">Message</label>
<textarea cols="49" rows="6"name="message"/></textarea>
 <input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" >
</form>
 </div>
```

and adding this to the form makes it work

```
 <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

but only if you click the html form submit button

This is the action page:

```
 <?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 $to = '@gmail.com' ;     //put your email address on which you want to receive the information
 $subject = 'Contact Form';   //set the subject of email.
 $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
 $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
 $message = "<table><tr><td>Name: </td><td>".$_POST['name']."</td></tr>
           <tr><td>E-Mail: </td><td>".$_POST['email']."</td></tr>
           <tr><td>Phone Number: </td><td>".$_POST['contact']."</td></tr>
           <tr><td>Message: </td><td>".$_POST['message']."</td>
           </tr></table>" ;
   mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
   header('Location: contact_thanks.php');
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: You could try calling the 'click' event of the underlying form's submit button.  i.e. trigger('click')

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can be done with straight JavaScript; set the id of the form to something (in your case `id="send"` then call the `Submit()` event like so:

```
document.forms["send"].submit();
```

where the string in the square brackets is the **id** of the form. Another method would be using the **name** of the form (in your case also "send"):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitform()
    {
      document.send.submit(); <-- 'send' refers to your form name
    }
</script>
```

Hope this works for you!

Adapted from code found [here](http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-submit.phtml).

**EDIT:** Question: in your original HTML does the form have a closing tag? That may be preventing the whole form from being found.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply!!
unfortunately my action page still displays Â 

I tried both of your responses, (the second I stripped everything away 
but the call itself)
I don't understand why changing from the input submit button to the javascript/jquery button makes any difference